# Learning C++ and got an error with an early example (constructor required before non-static data member)

Tags: c++

Following the book: [C++ Primer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0091I7FEQ) <sup>Stanley B Lippman, Josee Lajoie, Barbara Moo</sup>  5th Edition

Section 1.5 has this code to demonstrate standard operations (**>> istream** and **<< ostream**) with an object of type **Sales_item**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Sales_item.h"

int main(){
  Sales_item book;
  cin>> book;
  cout<< book << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

The file **Sales_item.h** is available from a download link given in the book.

I am using following CMake to compile my source ISBN0.cpp :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
add_executable(readISBN ISBN0.cpp)
```

While compiling I am getting the following error
`Sales_item2.h:11:7: error: constructor required before non-static data member for ‘Sales_item::units_sold’ has been parsed`

I have tried to cut down the original **Sales_item.h** into following to reproduce the error :

```
#ifndef SALESITEM_H
#define SALESITEM_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Sales_item {

friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Sales_item&);
friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, Sales_item&);

// private members as before
private:
    std::string bookNo;      // implicitly initialized to the empty string
    unsigned units_sold = 0; // explicitly initialized
    double revenue = 0.0;
public:
    // constructors are explained in section 7.1.4, pages 262 - 265
    // default constructor needed to initialize members of built-in type
    Sales_item() = default;
    Sales_item(const std::string &book): bookNo(book) { }
    Sales_item(std::istream &is) { is >> *this; }
public:
    // operations on Sales_item objects
    // member binary operator: left-hand operand bound to implicit this pointer
    Sales_item& operator+=(const Sales_item&);

    // operations on Sales_item objects
    std::string isbn() const { return bookNo; }
    double avg_price() const;

};

std::ostream& 
operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Sales_item& s)
{ ... }

std::istream& 
operator>>(std::istream& in, Sales_item& s)
{ ... }
```

**Can someone explain 1: What the error trying to tell? (in simple words) & 2: What modification is required to make the example work?**

It is so dis-heartening to see a beginner example not work!

Comment: What compiler do you use?

Comment: @IgorR. I think gcc (the default in Ubuntu Mate 16.04). `gcc --version` gives me **gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) 5.4.0 20160609**

Comment: c++ started supporting initialization of non-static members inside a class since c++ 11 onwards. Previous to that non-static members could not be initialized inside a class definition(what  the example tries to do here) . g++ version 5.4  supports this feature.  Probably you just need to compile with the  c++ flag like this (use g++ compiler for c++ and not gcc which is for c language):
**$ g++ -std=c++11 your_file.cpp -o your_program**

Comment: @dorKKnight That works! Wow.  Can you add that as an answer? a little bit of elaboration on `non-static` stuff would be very helpful. Thank you (I have wasted so much of my time trying to resolve this error!).

Comment: You could put this in your CMakeLists.txt: set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

Comment: @jignatius Thank you. I did add the line and also added the line `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)`

Comment: Are you sure the error message is from line 11? When I counted, line 11 was empty. I would rather expect the error in line 15.

Comment: @RolandIllig I had removed some comments after the `#ifndef` directive and a few places. I thought the compiler does not count those comment lines? (Sorry,  I edited the file for readability. yikes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

c++ started supporting initialization of non-static members inside a class since c++ 11 onwards. Previous to that non-static members could not be initialized inside a class definition(what the example tries to do here) . g++ version 5.4 supports this feature. Probably you just need to compile with the c++ flag like this (use g++ compiler for c++ and not gcc which is for c language):

$ g++ -std=c++11 your_file.cpp -o your_program

non-static members of a class are specific for that class and every object of the class gets their own individual instance of these members.
For more about non-static members please, check-out the following links:
[cpp ref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members)
and 
[this excellent c++ site for beginners](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-programming/8-5b-non-static-member-initialization/)

Comment: If I understand correctly, modifying the lines `unsigned units_sold = 0;  double revenue = 0.0;` should help. Is that correct?

Comment: **option 1**not assigning a default value to these member variables inside class definition is an option.
**option 2** modern C++ now supports your code, so there is no problem with your code and no  need to change these assignments. To compile it, all you need to do is to tell the compiler to use the c++ 11 features. by default, the g++ compiler does not use the support it has for C++ 11 features.